# Inner joins in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am looking to transfer this SQL to Linq:

```
SELECT raoe.AreaofExpID 

     , aoe.ServiceLineID 

     , raoe.ResponseID 

  FROM AreaofExp aoe 

 INNER 

  JOIN ResponseAreaOfExp raoe 

    ON aoe.AreaofExpID = raoe.AreaofExpID 

 INNER 

  JOIN Response resp 

    ON raoe.responseid = resp.responseid 

   AND resp.segmentid = 4;
```

After working on this I have got this:

```
var query = from aoe in _cctDBContext.AreaOfExp
                    join raoe in _cctDBContext.ResponseAreaOfExp on aoe.AreaofExpId equals raoe.AreaofExpId
                    join resp in _cctDBContext.Response on raoe.ResponseId equals resp.ResponseId
                    select new
                    {
                        raoe.AreaofExp,
                        aoe.ServiceLineId,
                        raoe.ResponseId
                    };
```

And now I am getting an error:

> Expected contextual keyword 'on'

I believe my second join is wrong but I am not sure how.

Comment: Hi! At this site, we require you to at least try to solve the problem yourself first. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Comment: I understand that.... And i am trying.. I will ammend my code to see what i have got.

Comment: @Esko - i have ammened my question... thanks !

Comment: [Expected contextual keyword 'on' Compiler Error CS0743](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0743)

Comment: I have got the on command in each of the join statements.

Comment: The query you have posted should not give that error. It's a valid LINQ query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I wrote to get your query, without modification, to work:

```
public static class _cctDBContext
{
    public static List<AreaOfExp> AreaOfExp = new List<AreaOfExp>();
    public static List<ResponseAreaOfExp> ResponseAreaOfExp = new List<ResponseAreaOfExp>();
    public static List<Response> Response = new List<Response>();
}

public class AreaOfExp
{
    public int AreaofExpId;
    public int ServiceLineId;
}

public class ResponseAreaOfExp
{
    public int AreaofExpId;
    public int AreaofExp;
    public int ResponseId;
}

public class Response
{
    public int ResponseId;
}
```

In other words, your query, as posted in the question, is fine and does not contain an error.

Comment: my visual studio was playing up - your right i dont have an error - thanks mate !